# I can't use php include in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, include

I try to do in a javascript function this:

```
document.getElementById('menuwrap').innerHTML = '<?php include("deffiles/menudefde.html")?>';
```

Whenever I insert the php part, my whole javascript stopped working. So nothing of the rest is execute any more. Anyone to help me?

Edit:
this:

```
document.getElementById('menuwrap').innerHTML = '<?php include("deffiles/menudefde.html")?>';
```

Became online this:

```
document.getElementById('menuwrap').innerHTML = '<html>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li id="menutext1"><a href="home.html">Home </a></li>
<li id="menutext2"><a href="afbeeldingen.html">Bilder</a></li>
<li id="menutext3"><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>';
```

Edit:

What i want is that i can change the buttons of my menu, which are stated in a html file. So i use javascript for the buttons, but the file is called with php. Is there another way to do so?

Comment: If the JavaScript isn't working, then look at the (generated) JavaScript to figure out why. **Then** worry about changing the PHP to remove that problem.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you're loading the content on page load, why not just inject the data in the HTML where it should be? And also, have a look at the source code. There's probably a ' in the included data.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Most likely you have a syntax error in the include. My guess is that there is a close quotation that is not escape somewhere in the html file. This is a very inelegant way to do what you are proposing

Comment: kba, because i want the stuff to be loaded when a buttoon is pressed.

Comment: @BalKortlevenStudios — Edit the question, don't put the code in a comment where it can't be formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some character in your `/menudefde.html` file that is illegal in a Javascript string. Most likely a newline character, you could have an unescaped `'` as well, which would terminate the string.

You'll need to escape every such character if you want to include it in a string like that.

However, there is probably a better solution to your overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the php code is correctly interpreted by your server your .html file might not be a valid string in JS.

Please check if it has no unescaped new lines, no ' characters etc or escape them.

Also check your console log if you see such errors.

You could use the json_encode function to escape that characters.

Answer (score -2):

It's a strange method to use JS and PHP. But, if you want to do this:

if you don't need to execute PHP in your include, you can make it like this:

```
document.getElementById('menuwrap').innerHTML = '<?php print str_replace("'", "\\'", file_get_contents('deffiles/menudefde.html')); ?>';
```

Comment: That's a very limited form of escaping that won't replace every character that is not allowed in a JS string.